# Chainrule and parameter integral

Tags: calculus

my supervisor totally puzzled when stating that the following is false.

Let $\Phi(x,u):=\int_0^u f(\xi)g(x,\xi)$ with smooth functions and $(x,u)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}$. Let $s(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ be smooth and differentiate $\Phi(x,s(x))$ in $x$.

So the chainrule would yields that 
$$\nabla \Phi(x,s(x))= D_x \Phi(x,s(x)) + \partial_u \phi(x,s(x)) \nabla s(x)=$$
$$= \int_0^{s(x)} f(\xi)D_x (g(x,\xi)) d\xi + f(s(x))g(x,s(x))\nabla s(x)$$

Is there really anything wrong with that? The $D_x$ shall only mean the derivative of $\Phi$ according to the first $n$ components. He says, that somewhere i should find a spatial derivative of the primitive (in $u$) of $g$. But I don't see where

Comment: So I think this is essentially the Leibniz rule for parameter integrals. And according to that rule the previous calculation should be correct. But maybe I just forgot something.